# Is there any "official" level test focused on American accent?

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

The courses and level tests which I know are only focused on British English, like Cambridge or Oxford, especially for the listening tests. Just for curiosity, I would like to test my level of listening against a test focused in the American accent. Do you know something "official" (i.e. widely accepted) like that?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TOEFL](https://www.ets.org/toefl) is a widely accepted test of English. It is based on the American dialect.

The [TOEIC](https://www.ets.org/toeic) test is also based on American English, with a focus on business English.